# How can i reload admob ads when they are closed

Tags: android, admob

Hey everyone i have an old admob game source code, and I wanted to add the new with this method : https://github.com/andoidam/admob_integration_lib

I have first tried interstitial but when i close it and move on to the game they don't appear anymore, I think the problem come from the closing code

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
Admob.get().skCloseInterstitial();
super.onStop();
}
```

so whats the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to reload the ad after it's closed. To do that, just load the ad after showing it:

```
        interstitial.show(); 
        interstitial.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
```

Comment: it didn't work man here's the error 

Syntax error on token "show", Identifier expected after this token

Answer (score 0):

reload the interstitial like this:

```
mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            // Load the next interstitial 
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        }
    });
```